# Help with construction of function to make integral converge

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $g\geq 0$ is a non-increasing function with $g(s)\downarrow 0$ as $s\uparrow \infty$. Show there exists $h\geq 0$ such that $$\int_0^{\infty} h(s)\,ds = \infty$$ and $$\int_0^{\infty} h(s) g(s)\,ds < \infty.$$

I've been trying to construct $h$ for this by looking at the case when $\int g\, ds < \infty$ and when it's not and using sequences of step functions, but I don't think I'm on the right track. Any ideas? This seems like a popular lemma too.

Comment: Maybe you just want the second integral to be finite.

Comment: you probably mean $\int_0^\infty h(s)g(s)\, ds<\infty$.

Comment: Yeah whoops you're right, typo.

Comment: I don't understand $h\geq 0$. Isn't $h$ a function? or perhaps you mean $h(s)\geq 0$?

Comment: $h$ is a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result doesn't change if we multiply $g$ with a positive constant, let us assume $g(0) = 1$.

Let $s_1 = 0$, and for $n \geqslant 1$, let

$$s_{n+1} = \inf \left\lbrace s > s_n + 1 : g(s) \leqslant \frac{1}{n+1}\right\rbrace.$$

Then $s_{n+1} \geqslant s_n + 1$, and on $(s_n,s_{n+1}]$ we have $g \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$. On $[s_n,s_{n+1})$, set

$$h(s) = \frac{1}{(s_{n+1}-s_n)(1+\log n)^2}.$$

Then

$$\int_0^\infty h(s)\,ds = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{s_n}^{s_{n+1}} h(s)\,ds = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1+\log n)^2} = \infty,$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty h(s)g(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{s_n}^{s_{n+1}} h(s)g(s)\,ds \leqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(1+\log n)^2} < \infty.$$